# Write a system of differential equation for the probabilities that the system is in state A, B, or C after time t.

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, renewal-processes

Consider the following process. A system is in one of the three states A, B, or C. A Poisson process is run with rate $\lambda$. At each event in this process, the following happens:

If the system is in state A, it moves to either B or C, chosen at random.

If it is system is in state B, it moves to state C.

If it is system is in state C, it moves to state A, B or C with probability 0.2, 0.3, or 0.5.

Write a system of differential equation for the probabilities that the system is in state A, B, or C after time t.

Can anyone suggest me how we think in this question. I never solve this type of question before.

Comment: Assuming unstated independence properties, this is a continuous time Markov chain. The transition rates could be determined if “chosen at random” could be clarified.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is deal with the rate $\lambda$. This is just a constant that tells what is the number of transitions per unit time. I prefer to think of it as the constant that allows me to write dimensionless equations. So if $\frac {dP}{dt}$ has units of $s^{-1}$, and $\lambda$ has the same units, then $\frac {dP}{\lambda dt}$ is dimensionless.

If the only transitions are described by the first equation, the change in probability for the $A$ state would be $$\frac{dP_A}{\lambda dt}=-P_A$$
This means that everything that was $A$ should be gone. These would transform into $B$ or $C$ state, with equal probability. This can be written as:$$\frac{dP_B}{\lambda dt}=0.5 P_A\\\frac{dP_C}{\lambda dt}=0.5 P_A$$

Now consider the effect of the transition from $B$ to $C$. That transition says that $P_B$ will decrease, and the rate is $-P_B$. Meanwhile $P_C$ will increase at the rate $P_B$. So now the three equations can be written as
$$\begin{align}\frac{dP_A}{\lambda dt}&=-P_A\\ \frac{dP_B}{\lambda dt}&=0.5 P_A-P_B\\\frac{dP_C}{\lambda dt}&=0.5 P_A+P_B\end{align}$$

The last is the transition from $C$. The rate of transition to $A$ will be $0.2P_C$, to $B$ will be $0.3P_C$. But you can also transition from $C$ to $C$. The rate for this will be $0.5P_C$. Note however that you need to decrease $P_C$ by all the transitions to the same or other states. We can therefore write the final equations as:
$$\begin{align}\frac{dP_A}{\lambda dt}&=-P_A+0.2P_C\\ \frac{dP_B}{\lambda dt}&=0.5 P_A-P_B+0.3P_C\\\frac{dP_C}{\lambda dt}&=0.5 P_A+P_B+(0.5-1)P_C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X(t)$ be the state of the system at time $t$, then $\{X(t):t\geqslant0\}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with infinitesimal generator
$$
Q = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\lambda  & \frac{\lambda }{2} & \frac{\lambda }{2} \\
 0 & -\lambda  & \lambda  \\
 \frac{\lambda }{5} & \frac{3 \lambda }{10} & -\frac{\lambda }{2} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
We have the Kolmogorov backward equations $P'(t) = QP(t)$, which are
\begin{align}
P'_{AA}(t) &= -\lambda P_{AA}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{BA}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{CA}(t)\\
P'_{AB}(t) &= -\lambda P_{AB}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{BB}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{CB}(t)\\
P'_{AC}(t) &= -\lambda P_{AC}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{BC}(t) + \frac\lambda 2P_{CC}(t)\\
P'_{BA}(t) &= -\lambda P_{BA}(t) + \lambda P_{CA}(t)\\
P'_{BB}(t) &= -\lambda P_{BB}(t) + \lambda P_{CB}(t)\\
P'_{BC}(t) &= -\lambda P_{BC}(t) + \lambda P_{CC}(t)\\
P'_{CA}(t) &= \frac\lambda 5 P_{AA}(t) + \frac{3\lambda}{10} P_{BA}(t) -\frac\lambda 2P_{CA}(t)\\
P'_{CB}(t) &= \frac\lambda 5 P_{AB}(t) + \frac{3\lambda}{10} P_{BB}(t) -\frac\lambda 2P_{CB}(t)\\
P'_{CC}(t) &= \frac\lambda 5 P_{AC}(t) + \frac{3\lambda}{10} P_{BC}(t) -\frac\lambda 2P_{CC}(t).
\end{align}
It is readily verified that the solution to these equations is given by the matrix exponential $e^{tQ}$, which in this case does not have a particularly nice closed form:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{8} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(7 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right) \sqrt{15}\right)+1\right) & \frac{1}{4} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(\sqrt{15} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)\right)+1\right) & \frac{5}{8}-\frac{1}{8} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(5 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)+3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right) \sqrt{15}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{24} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(3 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)+5 \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right) \sqrt{15}\right) & \frac{1}{12} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(9 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)-\sqrt{15} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)\right)+3\right) & \frac{1}{24} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(7 \sqrt{15} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)-15 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)\right)+\frac{5}{8} \\
 \frac{1}{120} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(7 \sqrt{15} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)-15 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)\right)+\frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{60} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(15 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right) \sqrt{15}\right) & \frac{5}{8}-\frac{1}{24} e^{-\frac{1}{4} (5 t \lambda )} \left(\sqrt{15} \sin \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)-9 \cos \left(\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} t \lambda \right)\right) \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
However, taking the limit as $t\to\infty$ yields
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{tQ} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{8} \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{8} \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{8} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
meaning that independent of the initial state, we have
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbb P(X(t) = i) = \begin{cases}
\frac18,& j=A\\
\frac14,& j=B\\
\frac58,& j=C.
\end{cases}
$$